# How to jump to method in taglist

Tags: linux, vim, ide

I am using vim with taglist plugin. But when open taglist everytime, it displays fields and method. But i don't care the fields in this class, i just want to just select a method and jump to it. Using search such as `/method` can actually solve this problem. But i think there must be better solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** straight from the docs ([taglist.txt](https://github.com/vim-scripts/taglist.vim/blob/master/doc/taglist.txt)):

> For example, to list only the classes and functions defined in a C++ language
>   file, add the following line to your .vimrc file:
>
> ```
>  let tlist_cpp_settings = 'c++;c:class;f:function'
> ```

---

This configures taglist to pass certain options to ctags, e.g.

ctags --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q

You could you `--list-kinds` to find out *which* kinds you want included.

Comment: My language is java. so can i using 'let tlist_cpp_settings = 'java;c:class;f:function'? I have tried it, but failed.And can i using set it in ex mode rather than in .vimrc. Thanks

Comment: I found `let s:tlist_def_java_settings ` in taglist.vim, and change it to `let s:tlist_def_java_settings = 'java;p:package;c:class;i:interface;' .
                              \ 'm:method'
`, then the field won't display in taglist.